# package javax.mail.internet does not exists although javax.mail api is present in my pom.xml

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

When I switch my branch to master and pull origin, Intellij gives

> java: package javax.mail.internet does not exist

I have following import statements.

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
```

However in my pom.xml file, I include javax.mail as below

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I also checked my File>Project Structures >Libraries tab and I have following
[maven dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atDiy.png)

Can you help me?

Comment: IntelliJ can sometimes get lost when switching branches. You could try to Rebuild the project or, when all else fails, invalidate the caches (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/invalidate-caches.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I deleted .idea directory and restarted Intellij. The error has gone

Comment: If it happens again - check if the Maven is able to build from the command line: `mvn compile`. Also, invoke **Reload** action in the Maven tool window.